# Generate a list of urls with two f-string substitutions in Python

Tags: python, f-string

I am trying to generate a list of urls by looping two word lists. I can do it one through f-string but I am not so sure how to do two at the same time. Any suggestion?

```py
tag_names = ['business', 'science', 'technology']
domain_names = ['bbc', 'cnn', 'nytimes']

for domain in domain_names:
    print(f'www.{domain}.com/{tag}')
```

Expected result

```
www.bbc.com/business
www.bbc.com/science
www.bbc.com/technology
www.cnn.com/business
www.cnn.com/science
www.cnn.com/technology
www.nytimes.com/business
www.nytimes.com/science
www.nytimes.com/technology
```

Comment: two loops? zip? itertools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` and a list comprehension:

```py
import itertools

tag_names = ['business', 'science', 'technology']
domain_names = ['bbc', 'cnn', 'nytimes']

[f'www.{domain}.com/{tag}' for domain, tag in itertools.product(domain_names, tag_names)]
```

output:

```
['www.bbc.com/business',
 'www.bbc.com/science',
 'www.bbc.com/technology',
 'www.cnn.com/business',
 'www.cnn.com/science',
 'www.cnn.com/technology',
 'www.nytimes.com/business',
 'www.nytimes.com/science',
 'www.nytimes.com/technology']
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use a nested loop:

```
tag_names = ['business', 'science', 'technology']
domain_names = ['bbc', 'cnn', 'nytimes']

print([f'www.{domain}.com/{tag}' for domain in domain_names for tag in tag_names])
```

Output:

```
['www.bbc.com/business',
 'www.bbc.com/science',
 'www.bbc.com/technology',
 'www.cnn.com/business',
 'www.cnn.com/science',
 'www.cnn.com/technology',
 'www.nytimes.com/business',
 'www.nytimes.com/science',
 'www.nytimes.com/technology']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
res=zip(tag_names,domain_names)
for i in res:
    print(f'www.{i[1]}.com/{i[0]}')
```